# In TypeScript, why can a function with return type void return something?

Tags: typescript

I don't quite understand the book *Learning JavaScript*. It first says when we have

```
const foo = (s: string): void => {
  return 1;  // ERROR
}
```

the function cannot return anything. But then the book immediately says, `void` says the return type is to be ignored, and it is good because we can use

```
arr.forEach(foo);
```

and `foo` is supposed to have return type `void`, but `foo` can return something and it is fine.

As an example, I tried this:

```
type Foo = (s: string) => number;

const foo: Foo = (s) => {
  return 1;
}

function bar(cb: (s: string) => void): boolean {
  return true;
}

bar(foo);
```

So `cb` is to have return type `void` but it can return something and it is fine.

However, that's contradictory to the first case in this question.  How can this be understood?

Comment: In your second example you are passing in a function of type `Foo`, doing nothing with it, and the returning a boolean. That's exactly what is written.  You don't do anything with the `cb` function that is passed in.  See [this demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAjFAvFAFAZwFxU8AJwEsA7AcwEpUA+KANziIBMBuAWAChOAzAVxIDGwInBJRuCROgq54SKAG9OUFVAIRgvAmMQtVAen1QAogCVTAeVOcAvp06GAtM5eu37j8-sdQkWAgAmVAwcPEJSShooEl4AWwAjCAJ2Lg4BUXxxQNlA4KwqFFolDlU1DS0dFLtUvkFhUSh4gEMCdAF4nLgAmUaEABsIJrFi0vb0AHJMOFiNAAsI8YoU0vVNbShCXggq72bWiS6loA) where I took your code and then called `cb` too

Comment: It is the difference between _defining_ and _using_. In the first example, you are _defining_ a function that does not return anything; hence, it is an error to return something. In the second and third, you can pass a function that _does_ return something, because the function it is passed to can just ignore it. More technically, the passed in callback is **assignable** to the parameter's type.

Comment: See the [TS FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void) for info. And [TS Handbook - Comparing two types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions). And https://stackoverflow.com/q/68305480/15261914 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/74730905/15261914.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't give an error in your example ([see it in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAzgLiu4AnASwDsBzASmQD4oiBXAWwCMI8BuAKHYGM4jcoAZgmzxEKDBSTUA3uyjyoeCMFp4iUAIwcAvpwG0iXYAV5RGAQzyoujbBmy5CpSdQBucAgBMy2RggA2EObqsgqKyqrq%20LQQOpwWVkJwZKxAA)) because `(s: string) => number` **does satisfy** ([proof in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nA6gS2ACwGp2QEygXigAoBnALihOACdkA7AcwEoCA%20KAN2xwG4AoPgGM4dKlABmCCvCSpM3AsRJMKdAK4BbAEYRqbKAG8%20UE1GoRga6nSgBGfgF8%20QA)) `(s: string) => void`.

The reason is that you can totally define a function as `(s: string) => number`, but use it as a `(s: string) => void`. You just have to ignore its return value.

For example:

```
type Foo = (s: string) => number;

const foo: Foo = (s) => {
    return 1;
}

function bar(cb: (s: string) => void): boolean {
    cb('hello')
    return true;
}

bar(foo);
```